# probability problem

Tags: statistics

3 machines (a1,a2,a3) produce parts

a1=45%
a2=35%
a3=20%
10% of a1 are defective
6% of a2 is defecyive
2% of a3 is defective
a)prob of a random part chosen to not be defective
b)part produced by a1

a) i thought of finding the defective first then subtracting it from 1 to get the not defective 
so...defective= d
p(d|a1)=.1
p(d|a2)=.06
p(d|a3)=.02
p(d)= p(dUa1)+p(dUa2)+p(dUa3)=.1x.45+.06x.35+.02x.2
then 1-(above calculation) should give me the not damaged part right?

for b is it just .45? because it asks for the prob that it was produced by a1, so 45% is produced by a1 so 45/100?

Comment: correct on both counts

Comment: i was almost positive about the first part but the second seems to be too easy to be a part of such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you think (b) is too easy, it perhaps meant to ask what is the chance a *defective* part is produced by $a_1$?

If that's so, it is
$$
\frac{\mathbb{P}[\text{defective part} \cap \text{produced by} a_1]}
     {\mathbb{P}[\text{part is defective}}
 = \frac{0.1 \cdot 0.45}{0.1 \cdot 0.45 + 0.06 \cdot 0.35 + 0.02 \cdot 0.2}
 = \frac{9}{14} \approx 64.3 \%.
$$